# how to display data from web service in web content portlet in Liferay 6.2?

Tags: web-services, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I have to display html content in web content display portlet which will be coming from web service response in Liferay 6.2. I have created wsdl jar as we always do for accessing the web service in custom portlets. But i am not sure how to access these web servive in Web content display portlet. Can you guys please help me how to perform this or let me know if its not possible

Answer (score 0):

1. Use wsdl of the service to generate client js code with a wsdl to js converter.
2. Use this generated js in your web content display:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://foo/bar.js"></script>
   ```

This should work though I haven't tried it myself.